# Neo4j can you add a WHERE clause after a MERGE statement?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a functional CQL query below that returns 3 node types and 2 relationships.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/parsed_message_amp_v2.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From}) 
MERGE (b:Url_Sub_Fld { name: row.Url_Sub_Fld})
MERGE (c:Recipient { name: row.To})
WITH a,b,c,row
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1 
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(b, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, c) YIELD rel as rel2
RETURN a,b,c
```

I would like to add a where clause that only graphs nodes where the b.Url_Sub_Fld is the string `false`.  Of course the below example fails.  How to you do something like this?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/parsed_message_amp_v2.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From}) 
MERGE (b:Url_Sub_Fld { name: row.Url_Sub_Fld})
MERGE (c:Recipient { name: row.To})
WHERE b.Url_Sub_Fld = "false" 
WITH a,b,c,row
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1 
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(b, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, c) YIELD rel as rel2
RETURN a,b,c
```

Comment: What is supposed to be the semantics of such `WHERE` clause? `MERGE` in general works in a way that if it can't match what you define it creates new nodes - is that what you want? If so you can just add this to the MERGE clause: `MERGE (b:Url_Sub_Fld { name: row.Url_Sub_Fld, anotherProperty:"false"})`

Comment: That makes sense.  If I would like to get the other data that does not include "false" can I define it in the MERGE statement?

Comment: Use a regular MATCH clause for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to filter your results at that point, use WITH followed by WHERE. It sounds like you only want to filter what is returned back, so apply that after your CALLs and before your RETURN:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/parsed_message_amp_v2.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From}) 
MERGE (b:Url_Sub_Fld { name: row.Url_Sub_Fld})
MERGE (c:Recipient { name: row.To})
WITH a,b,c,row
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1 
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(b, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, c) YIELD rel as rel2
WITH a,b,c,row
WHERE b.Url_Sub_Fld = "false" 
RETURN a,b,c
```

Comment: Made a small change to where this is applied, as I just realized you seem to want to filter returned results only, but still apply all operations (your merge relationship calls) to all results.

Comment: Thank you again, so much to learn...  WHERE after the WITH when using a MERGE @InverseFalcon